# What kind of data does texImage2D accept?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to offload some matrix computations to a fragment shader, using WebGL.

I'm trying to send my matrix as an RGB 2D texture, using `texImage2D`, but I don't know how the data must be formated.

I tried this (for a square 2x2 matrix):

```
var textureData = new Uint8Array([
  0, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0,
  2, 0, 0,  3, 0, 0
]);
//...
var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  textureData);
```

But I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
>   'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the
>   signature provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to send my matrix as an RGB 2D texture

I'm afraid that `UNSIGNED_BYTE` will not provide enough precision for that, you may want to use the [OES_texture_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_texture_float/) extension and create your texture as a floating point texture instead.

> I don't know how the data must be formated

The available signatures for texImage2D can be found in the [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/):

```
void texImage2D(
    GLenum target,
    GLint level,
    GLint internalformat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLint border,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    ArrayBufferView? pixels
);

void texImage2D(
    GLenum target,
    GLint level,
    GLint internalformat,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    TexImageSource? source
);
```

Where TexImageSource is of type

```
ImageBitmap
ImageData
HTMLImageElement
HTMLCanvasElement
HTMLVideoElement
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload data from an typearray like `Uint8Array` you need to use the version of `texImage2D` that takes a typedArray.

That one is

```
void texImage2D(
    GLenum target,
    GLint level,
    GLint internalformat,
    GLsizei width,
    GLsizei height,
    GLint border,
    GLenum format,
    GLenum type,
    ArrayBufferView? pixels
);
```

Also you should be aware that WebGL, like OpenGL defaults to having `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` set to 4 bytes meaning every row of pixels/texels must be a multiple of 4 bytes. You can change that to 1 byte by calling

```
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

I only bring that up because since you're uploading an `RGB`/`UNSIGNED_BYTE` texture that's 3 bytes per pixel which means if you upload a 2x2 pixel texture each row is 6 bytes. WebGL will pad that to 8 bytes so it will expect a buffer 14 bytes long (8 bytes for the first row where only the first 6 bytes are used and 6 for the last row. It doesn't care about padding the last row. If you set `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to 1 then that problem goes away.

As an aside you could make the argument it should have just defaulted to 1 but WebGL is following OpenGL and in OpenGL it defaults to 4.